# Connecting to Oracle using Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, odp.net, odac

I am very new to Oracle and trying to create a test application on Visual Studio 2008 framework 3.5 in C#.

I have a basic requirement of generating a simple xml file from an Oracle Database table located on a Server.

My Oracle Client and Server version are as below[image: Oracle Client and Server version]

I also noticed that I have sqlnet.ora and TnsNames.ora files on C:\DevSuiteHome_5\NETWORK\ADMIN which has connection details of the server.

So, to connect to Oracle Database :
1.First of all, I need to install [ODAC](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html) and then add the following reference :

```
using Oracle.DataAccess.Client;
using Oracle.DataAccess.Types;
```

All this seems perfectly understandable, but which 64-bit version of ODAC do I have to install from the above link/ or can I install the latest?
Any examples/links for creating a sample application with database on the sevrer would be really helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just found out that I could install the latest ODAC. I installed ODAC 11.1.0.7.20 and it worked fine.

Thanks